Computing the Cohomology of Knot Space vs Cohomology of Non-compact Knots
In Vassiliev's paper of the cohomology of knot spaces, he considers the long-knots or non-compact knots i.e. embedding of $S^1$ into $S^3$ that go through a fixed point.
He claims that this is meant to help computations however it is not explained why. Where do the difficulties lie if we were to just consider embeddings $S^1\rightarrow S^3$?
